# Spring security Delete method is Forbidden

Tags: spring-security

I created web application.
pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
     <version>3.1.4</version>
 </dependency>
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.yaml/snakeyaml -->
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
     <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
     <version>2.0</version>
 </dependency>

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-config -->
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
     <version>6.1.4</version>
 </dependency>
```

file controller

```
@RequestMapping("/passports")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PassportController {

    @Operation(
description = "Удаление паспорта из таблицы",
summary = "delete passport",
hidden = false
    )
    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "PassportResponse")
    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
public void deleteById(
            @PathVariable(name = "id") final long id
throws Exception {
passportComponent.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

file WebSecurityConfigurer

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfigurer {

    @Bean
public InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsService() {
UserDetails user = User.withUsername("user")
                .password(encoder().encode("userPass"))
                .roles("USER")
                .build();
return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }

    @Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

XorCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler requestHandler = new XorCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler();

requestHandler.setCsrfRequestAttributeName(null);

http
            .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET).permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
             )
            .csrf((csrf) -> csrf
                .csrfTokenRequestHandler(new CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler())
            )
            .csrf((csrf) -> csrf
                .csrfTokenRequestHandler(requestHandler)
            )
            .csrf((csrf) -> csrf
                .csrfTokenRepository(new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository())
            )
            .csrf((csrf) -> csrf
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
            )
            .csrf((csrf) -> csrf
                .csrfTokenRequestHandler(new XorCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler())
            )
            .csrf((csrf) -> csrf
                .ignoringRequestMatchers("/no-csrf"))
            .csrf(Customizer.withDefaults()).csrf((csrf) -> csrf
                .csrfTokenRepository(new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository()))
            .csrf((csrf) -> csrf
                .csrfTokenRequestHandler(new CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler())
            );
return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
public InMemoryUserDetailsManager inMemoryUserDetailsManager(){
List<UserDetails> userDetailsList = new ArrayList<>();
userDetailsList.add(User.withUsername("user").password(encoder().encode("userPass"))
                .roles("EMPLOYEE", "USER").build());
return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(userDetailsList);
    }
    @Bean
public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

@GetMapping() is Ok
I try use delete method in postman. But i received answer `"status": 403,"error": "Forbidden" .`
what i do wrong ?
how i can solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Usually this message(`"status": 403,"error": "Forbidden" .`) is generated because you are using `CSRF` enabled, in this case you have some misconfiguration about it because first of all in `filterChain` i am seeing that you are disabling it `.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)` and after it your are do some validation/verification on it(

```
        .csrf((csrf) -> csrf
                        .csrfTokenRequestHandler(new CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler())
                    )
     ...
return http.build();
```

). What is really wrong way in my opinion.

To be sure that here is the problem I suggest you to rewrite the `filterChain` Bean method. From what you have to something like it(To avoid using it in production).

```
  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
        .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
        .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET).permitAll()
            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated());
    return http.build();
  }
```

And after it the `HttpMethod.DELETE` is going to work.

By the way also you have to read about `CSRF`.

Some good refereances about it:

[CSRF](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/features/exploits/csrf.html)

[OWASP CSRF](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/csrf)